# Setting permissions for a user on linux system so they cannot access parent directory

Tags: linux

I create a user with useradd and edited the /etc/passed file  but the user can still see parent and can go in to parent directorys

how can I restrict him from going into parent directory.

Comment: What is the actual use case?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want that? What are exactly the parent directory?

Often, the home directory of user `foo` is `~foo` i.e. `/home/foo`

It depends upon the permissions on *others* home directories. So if there is user `bar` you might `chmod o-rwx /home/bar` ; and you could set up groups and group permission, etc...

Or perhaps try (with caution and care) `chmod o-rwx /home/`

You could also use some [restricted shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell) for `foo` e.g. [rbash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) or [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/), configure it wisely, and `chsh foo /bin/rbash`

See also [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page)